# Sunspot Solr fulltext search and will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, will-paginate

The following query is working like a charm:

```
@styles = Style.search { fulltext params[:q] }
```

The problem I'm having is with pagination. Here is the same query with pagination:

```
@styles = Style.search { fulltext params[:q]; paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:page_limit] }
```

I have 11 `Style` records.

If I have `:page => 1` and `:per_page => 10` when I search for the 11th record, I get an empty array returned for `@styles.results`

If I set `:page=>2` and do the same search I get the 11th style record.

```
[11] pry(#<StylesController>)> params[:page]=2
=> 2
[12] pry(#<StylesController>)> x=Style.search {fulltext params[:q]; paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:page_limit] }
=> <Sunspot::Search:{:fq=>["type:Style"], :q=>"hel", :fl=>"* score", :qf=>"name_textp full_name_textp", :defType=>"dismax", :start=>10, :rows=>10}>
[13] pry(#<StylesController>)> x.results
=> [#<Style id: 15...>]
```

**I thought the point was to paginate the search results, not the actual records in their entirety**

What's going on here, and how do I fix it?

**EDIT**

Ok, let me try explaining this another way. Let's say I have these six records:

```
1 => 'a'
2 => 'b'
3 => 'c'
4 => 'd'
5 => 'e'
6 => 'f'
```

Let's say I try to search for 'f'

```
Letter.search { fulltext 'f'; paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 5 }
```

My result will be an empty array `[]`

Now let's say I try

```
Letter.search { fulltext 'f'; paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 6 }
```

Now my result is [6 => 'f']

Comment: The explanation is a bit confusing to me. Can you put the result of "when it works like a charm", depending on your default page size it could be quite different. From the data you show everything seems to make sense. What is what you think is wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing your parameters are not what you think they are. Can you output your results without cryptic params?

Comment: How do you index your model? fulltext isn't magical, you need to pass the fields you want to search on and you need to index those as `text` in your `searchable` block. Can you show that info too?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/funkdified/6135333

Comment: It's not a full text problem, it's a pagination issue. The description of my problem is a simplification for illustration. See gist for my setup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**my thoughts:**

get the results from solr then search your model by ids that solr returned and paginate them, something like this:

```
@search = Sunspot.search(Snippet) do
   fulltext params[:search]
end
@styles = Style.where(id: @search.results.map(&:id)).page(params[:page]).per(5)
```

---

**what I understood from docs:** *I didn't tried it*

By default, Sunspot requests the first 30 results from Solr. That means you can have 100 of records that might match the searching criteria but you'll see only the first 30, to see the others you have to add the paginate to your solr search, like:

```
search = Style.search do
  fulltext "my cool style"
  paginate :page => 2
end
```

in this case, you should be able to access 2 page. To update the number of sunspot requests you need to write:

```
search = Style.search do
  fulltext "my cool style"
  paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 50
end
```

it should give you 50 results in one page, or `paginate :page => 2, :per_page => 50` and results should be divided in 2 pages with max 50 results each.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not even sure why it wasn't working, as suddenly it's working as expected. Before I was only able to find the record in the console by changing per_page higher, but now it's coming up as expected with a typical per_page setting. Here's some points anyway.

Comment: I'd recommend using `hits` instead of `results` in this case, to avoid needlessly instantiating all the objects twice, see [here](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#hits-vs-results).

Answer (score 2):

Try supply a fallback to `per_page` like so:

```
@search = Style.search do
  fulltext params[:q]
  paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: (params[:per] || 15))
end
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this does not fix the problem. Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. So I removed :per_page tag in my search

And changed my query as

```
@styles = Style.search { fulltext params[:q]; paginate :page => params[:page]}
```

To set the per_page_limit, I used the following code in my initializers

```
Sunspot.config.pagination.default_per_page = 20
```

Comment: Thanks will try this tomorrow and get back to you! :)

Comment: I'm sorry, this does not fix the problem. Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "hits" method.

In the controller

```
@search = User.search do 
  with :name, 'joe'
end
```

In the view

```
<% @search.results.each do |result| %>
    <%= result.name %>
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate @search.hits unless @search.nil? %>
```

Comment: using "hits" is key for the will_paginate method in the view.  "results" only returns the quantity of results from the paginated aspect in the model.search method. "hits", on the other hand, provides an array of records that reflects the quantity of the entire search, therefore allowing the paginated results to work properly.